# MEAN stack node require is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose

I am trying my hand at an application on the MEAN stack and have come across an issue with using nodes `require` function.

My current structure is as follows:

```
-- app
   -- images
   -- scripts
      -- app.js // app configuration
      -- contollers.js 
      -- models.js
      -- routes.js
   -- styles // scss partials
-- node_modules
-- public
   -- images
   -- scripts
      -- app.js  // concatenated and uglified js from app/scripts
   -- styles // concatenated and compressed scss partials
   -- vendor // third party libraries
   -- views // html partials
   bower.json
   index.html
   gruntfile.js
   pacakge.json
   server.js
```

**Note:** I know that this is not the best way to structure my app and will be refactoring it so that it uses a more [modular system](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure) down the track.

The issue I am having is when I add `var mongoose = require('mongoose');` to the models.js file I get the following error:

*ReferenceError: require is not defined*

The puzzling thing is that this line works perfectly in server.js, why does it not work in models.js?

Comment: Seems odd, it certainly should work in models.js, assuming you're still running it in node and not the browser. Browsers don't have a `require` method built-in, hence the usage of concatenation build processes.

Comment: I am running this through a browser. That sounds like the issue.  How do I get around this? All of the tutorials I have been following don't seem to do anything special to get require to work in the browser. I don't fully get how this node voodoo works.

Comment: well, you can't talk to a database directly from the browser, so i doubt you should be including mongoose in a browser script.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense :). So the whole application needs to be running through node. It sounds like I have to rethink my approach entirely. Do you know of any good resources / tutorials that could guide me? I have seen many but have no idea which I should trust.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I didn't follow any when i began with this, instead i used yeoman-generators and then reverse-engineered them until I understood what they were doing.

Comment: Here's one, though i haven't used this one specifically: http://meanjs.org/generator.html

Comment: I started out with the yeoman build but then decided I would try an learn it from scratch. Maybe it is best if i do the same as you and work from an existing generator and revers engineer it. Thanks for the point in the right direction :)

Comment: how are you running your app?

Comment: I have since refactored my app structure so that my model, routes, database etc are all running on the server side. I was getting confused with what need to run through angular and what was running through express / node. I still have a lot to learn but I managed to get around this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I had this all backwards. I was not running the model on the server side and as such, node's `require` function was not available. Which seems so obvious now that I understand this a little better.

I have since restructured my app after reading up on how structure MEAN apps.

If anyone is having problems understanding how this MEAN magic works, the best resource I came across was [this little collection of mean tutorials](https://scotch.io/tag/mean) on scotch.io

**Most notably this tutorial on [setting up a mean stack single page application](https://scotch.io/tutorials/setting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-application)**